# which preposition does fit in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, word-request

I want to say the following sentence, but I'm not sure about the correct preposition to put in the highlighted blank.

> I can bring my e-books with me on my cell phone which is not possible **[...]** paper books.

[for/with/through/...] ?

Comment: I am not sure that the preposition 'with' can be used here to mean the situation in which you have to bring paper books and you cannot do it. Does 'with' mean, by any chance, 'using something' or 'with use of something' or 'by means of something', which is incorrect in this context?

Comment: Maybe "which is not possible in case of" works here. Consider 'in respect of', 'in regard to'.

Comment: Nice phrase, "in case of".

Comment: Maybe it's "nice", but it's wrong for your sentence—"paper books" are not a situation.  Also, Mok, you might like to change your question title to "Which preposition fits (in) this sentence?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the preposition **with**:

> I can bring my e-books with me on my cell phone, which is not possible **with** paper books.

I would also add a comma before "which".